# Video out on iPod dock: pre-iOS versus iOS

Tags: ipod, dock, video-adapter, lightning

I have an iPod dock with Video Out. It says on the box that it only supports pre-iOS devices for that (iPod classic and the like), and it certainly does not seem to do anything with my iPod Touch (audio and remote control work fine, though).

Is this something that can be solved with an additional (cheap) adapter, or are the two Video Out systems fundamentally different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the old video output is not compatible with iOS devices, even with an adapter. To see, why, [here's a diagram](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml) of the iPod dock connector pinout. Notice that there are some video output pins that are only used for older iPods.

Comment: So how does video get out of the new iPods? Completely digital (something like USB)?